# Complex query variables in GraphQL (via Gatsby)

Tags: graphql, gatsby

I am building a localized static website using Gatsby, with the help of `gatsby-plugin-intl`. This plugin adds a context variable named `intl` to pages (including template-based pages), which is an object: https://github.com/wiziple/gatsby-plugin-intl/blob/master/src/gatsby-node.js#L27-L34

I would like to access the `intl.language` variable from the context within a page query. This is my (failing) code at this stage:

```
query($slug: String!, $intl: String) {
  contentfulPerson(slug: {eq: $slug}, node_locale: {eq: $intl.language}) {
    name
  }
}
```

Contentful is the headless CMS I use and from which I would like to fetch data in the correct locale.

Obviously this code has two problems: `$intl` is not a string, and `$intl.language` is not syntactically correct. But I don't know how to fix either problem.

I guess I could either fork the plugin or do something in my own `gatsby-node.js` to make the language available as a top-level variable in the context, but I'm interested to know if there is a way to do it directly.
The Gatsby docs say that query variables can be complex (https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/graphql-reference/#query-variables) but in the example they provide, they don't show how the types are defined or how to access a property within these variables.

---

EDIT : I tried moving the language to a top-level context variable in my `gatsby-node.js` using this code:

```js
exports.onCreatePage = ({page, actions}) => {
  const { createPage, deletePage } = actions
  deletePage(page)
  createPage({
    ...page,
    context: {
      ...page.context,
      language: page.context.intl.language
    }
  })
}
```

but the program runs out of memory (even when increasing `max_old_space_size`)

Comment: This is not a problem I have had to deal with yet personally, but I have done some research on it. I think looking at [this repo](https://github.com/LekoArts/portfolio/blob/0e5672921fe484ec57af45db3ec2ba9186f33d6d/gatsby-node.js#L50-L88) might help you with your problem. You can look at `pages/index.jsx` afterwards to see how they have queried it.

Comment: Thanks for the reference @FranklinFarahani. I did come across it but unfortunately in this case the language is directly available as a top level variable, which makes it easy to query.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can move the `language` field to a top-level context by doing this:

```
exports.onCreatePage = ({ page, actions }) => {
  const { createPage, deletePage } = actions
  const oldPage = Object.assign({}, page)

  page.context.language = page.context.intl.language;
  if (page.context.language !== oldPage.context.language) {
    // Replace new page with old page
    deletePage(oldPage)
    createPage(page)
  }
}
```

Checking if the field has changed avoids the infinity loop.

Comment: Well played! Thanks :)

Comment: Worked like a charm!