# Zero results found: GraphQL query on live deploy with WordPress API and Gatsby on Netlify

Tags: reactjs, graphql, gatsby, wordpress-rest-api, netlify

I'm confused as to why, in local development running `gatsby build && gatsby serve` on `localhost:9000`, I'm able to programmatically create category pages that query and output a list of posts based on a category `slug` variable but when I deploy the site to Netlify, the category pages show zero results, regardless of category or how many posts match the query.

```js
// gatsby.node
exports.createPages = async ({ graphql, actions }) =>  {

    const { createPage } = actions
    const categoryTemplate = path.resolve('src/templates/categoryTemp.js')

    const result = await graphql(`
        query {
            allWordpressCategory {
                edges {
                    node {
                        id
                        path
                        slug
                        name
                        description
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    `)

    const { allWordpressCategory } = result.data

    allWordpressCategory.edges.forEach(({ node }) => {
        if (node.slug === 'portfolio') return
        createPage({
            path: node.path,
            component: categoryTemplate,
            context: {
                id: node.id,
                slug: node.slug,
                name: node.name,
                description: node.description,
                url: node.path
            }
        })
    })
```

That `context` property in the `createPage` action, containing the `slug` for the category, is passed to the `categoryTemplate` page/component I've set up (`categoryTemp.js`).

The `slug` is used in the GraphQL query as a filtering variable and should return all the posts the match that category:

```js
// src/templates/categoryTemp.js
import React from "react"
import { graphql, Link } from "gatsby"
import Layout from "../components/layout/layout"
import PageContent from "../components/layout/pageContent"

export default ({ data, pageContext }) => {

    const { allWordpressPost } = data 

    return (
        <Layout path={pageContext.url} layoutClass={"category"}>

            <PageContent>
                <h2>{allWordpressPost.totalCount} posts in category: {pageContext.name}</h2>
                <ul>
                    {allWordpressPost.edges.map(({ node }, idx ) => (
                        <li key={idx}><Link to={node.path} title={node.title}>{node.title}</Link></li>
                    ))} 
                </ul>
            </PageContent>
           
        </Layout>
    )

}

export const categoryQuery = graphql`
    query($slug: String!) {
        allWordpressPost(filter: {categories: {elemMatch: {slug: {eq: $slug}}}}) {
            edges {
                node {
                    id
                    title
                    path
                }
            }
            totalCount
          }
    }
`
```

As I said before, this works locally in development and when I run `gatsby build && gatsby serve`, which is usually a good [production test](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/overview-of-the-gatsby-build-process/#what-happens-when-you-run-gatsby-build) to see how your gatsby site will fare on a server. However, the live site fails to return any query matches:

[image: console message]
[image: front-facing result]

I'm wondering if there's perhaps some intermediary step that I need to take, like [overriding the default context property](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/creating-and-modifying-pages/#pass-context-to-pages) when programmatically processing and creating these category templates but I'm afraid I'm a little doubtful I'll be able to figure this out promptly or at all.

Similarly, I'm seeing this pattern a lot: [Complex query variables in GraphQL (via Gatsby)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56341100/complex-query-variables-in-graphql-via-gatsby) but need a nudge in how to implement it.

Does anyone have any ideas or suggestions?

```js
// gatsby-config.js

module.exports = {
    siteMetadata: {
        ...
    },
    plugins: [
        `gatsby-plugin-react-helmet`,
        {
            resolve: `gatsby-source-filesystem`,
            options: {
                name: `images`,
                path: `${__dirname}/src/images`,
            },
        },
        `gatsby-transformer-sharp`,
        `gatsby-plugin-sharp`,
        {
            resolve: `gatsby-plugin-manifest`,
            options: {
                name: "Peak Websites",
                short_name: "Peak Websites",
                start_url: "/",
                background_color: "#27688E",
                theme_color: "#27688E",
                display: "minimal-ui",
                icon: "src/images/logo/Logo_squared.png",
            },
        },
        {
            resolve: `gatsby-source-wordpress`,
            options: {
                baseUrl: `pathtomysite.com`,
                protocol: `https`,
                useACF: false,
                verboseOutput: false,
                hostingWPCOM: false
            }
        },
        `gatsby-plugin-sass`,
        {
            resolve: `gatsby-plugin-prefetch-google-fonts`,
            options: {
                fonts: [{
                    family: `Montserrat`,
                    variants: [`300`,`300i`,`400`,`400i`,`700`]
                }],
            },
        }, {
            resolve: `gatsby-plugin-google-analytics`,
            options: {
                trackingId: process.env.GA_TRACKING_CODE,
                head: false,
            },
        },
        // `gatsby-plugin-sitemap`
        // this (optional) plugin enables Progressive Web App + Offline functionality
        // To learn more, visit: https://gatsby.dev/offline
        // `gatsby-plugin-offline`,
  ],
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Two adjustments I made to solve this problem.

First, I modified my query to the data layer under `allWordpressPosts` in my `gatsby-node.js` to query `categories > slug`, i.e:

```
allWordpressPost {
    edges {
        node {
            id
            wordpress_id
            status
            path
            categories {
                slug
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then I wrote a filter function inside the function component **before** rendering the list of matching posts.

```
const filteredPosts = allWordpressPost.edges.filter(({node}) => {
    return node.categories.some(({ slug }) => slug === pageContext.slug)
})

return (
        <Layout path={pageContext.url} layoutClass={"category"}>

            <PageContent>
                <h2>{allWordpressPost.totalCount} posts in category: {pageContext.name}</h2>
                <ul>
                    {filteredPosts.map(({ node }, idx ) => (
                        <li key={idx}><Link to={node.path} title={S(node.title).decodeHTMLEntities().s}>{S(node.title).decodeHTMLEntities().s}</Link></li>
                    ))}
                </ul>
            </PageContent>
           
        </Layout>
    )
```

`pageContext` is passed to each category page at build time and contains all the props, including `slug` that I defined in the `createPages` action:

```
createPage({
    path: node.path,
    component: categoryTemplate,
    context: {
        id: node.id,
        slug: node.slug,
        ...
    }
})
```

[image]